# How a can I extract these three numbers fast?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stl

I have an `std::string` which contains 3 numbers which are separated by spaces
for instance: `123334 33335 54544`. How a can I extract these three numbers fast?

```
int r = ... /* 123334 */
int g = ... /* 33335 */
int b = ... /* 54544*/
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/):

```
std::string numbers = "123334 33335 54544";
std::istringstream parse(numbers);
int r, g, b;

parse >> r;
parse >> g;
parse >> b;

if (!parse)
   throw std::runtime_error("invalid string");
```

Comment: PHP-style: `(parse >> r >> g >> b) || throw std::invalid_argument("invalid string");`

Answer (score 3):

Create a `stringstream` object, assign to it your string, then use `operator>>` to read the 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be.

```
std::string numbers = "123334 33335 54544";
std::istringstream iss(numbers);
std::vector<int> int_numbers;
std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::back_inserter<std::vector<int> >(int_numbers), 
    boost::lambda::bind(&boost::lexical_cast<int, std::string>, boost::lambda::_1)
    );
```

But then you need lambda and lexical cast from the boost library.

Comment: Why so complex? Just use `std::istream_iterator<int>` directly. That saves you the transform, and therefore also the lambda and lexical_cast.

Comment: But you don't get an error. I like the exception thrown by lexical_cast

Comment: That's also possible in standard C++, with `iss.exceptions( std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit );`